# JQuery ProgressBar change default colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I"m using JQuery Progress-Bar and want to change his white\grey color schema.

Currenly- empty space is colored with White and filled space colored with Grey.

[image: Progress Bar defualt color schema]

My needed colors schema: *Black for empty spaces* and *Red for Filled spaces*.

This is how my html looks like:

```
<div id="progress" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <div id="progressbar"><div class="progress-label">Loading...</div></div>
</div>
```

This is how I'm controlling my progress back behaviour:

```
var progressbar = $("#progressbar"), progressLabel = $(".progress-label");
progressbar.progressbar({
    value: false,
    change: function () {
        progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "%");
    },
    complete: function () {
        progressLabel.text("Complete!");
    }
});
```

How can I changed this colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two classes that you want to style:

- **ui-progressbar** for empty spaces
- **ui-progressbar-value** for filled spaces

**background** parameter determines color in both cases.

CSS schema for your needs would be something like this:

```
  .ui-progressbar {
    background: black;
    //... other values ...
  }

  .ui-progressbar-value {
    background: red;
    //... other values ...
  }
```

Here is working sample: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vzMY3QV351yrlfQObAbk?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Check here for info on theming: http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/

You should be able to define the colors by editing the main jquery-ui CSS, specifically the ui-progressbar class (for the main container) and the ui-progressbar-value class for the percentage/progress.